# Javascript code for alphabetizing divs

Tags: javascript

I'm editing a web page that has a list of doctors names and images wrapped in a div. I'm adding more to that list and my client wants all of the names in alphabetical order now. As apposed to manually doing that (I know my client will also be adding more doctors in the future)I tried writing a script to do the work for me. I wrapped each doctor in a div called "alphabetize," and set a span id of "lastName" around each doctor's last name.

```
<div class="alphabetize large-6 columns sameheight-wrap">
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns sameheight  PadT20"> <img src="../imgs/dev/crna-staff/John-Doe.jpg" alt=" John Doe, CRNA" class="pictureBottomBorder"> </div>
    <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns contenttable sameheight  PadT20">
      <div class="border vmid text-center bgdblue PadB"> <span class="white medium"><strong>John<span id="lastName">Doe</span></strong><br>
        </span> <span class="white PadT5"> MSN, Thomas Jefferson University School of Nurse Anesthesia</span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I placed the following script on that page;

```
<script>
var $divs = $("div.alphabetize");

$(function() {
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
   return $(a).find("#lastName").text() > $(b).find("#lastName").text();
});
$("#alpha").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});
</script>
```

For some reason, the script is not working correctly. Doctors are out of order and i also need to add a variable to the code that sorts the last names with the first 3 letters. Can anyone help? Javascript is not my strong suit. Not sure if I missed something.

Comment: before I attempt an answer, are you opposed to keeping your doctor's names in a javascript object/array? manipulating the page afterward is not very efficient.

Comment: ids need to be singular on a page.

Comment: jdu - I'm open to any solutions that don't involve me manually ordering a list of 60 plus doctors. Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: @Eddie have a look at my pure JS answer and suggestions, it should help you out.

Comment: @somethinghere - worked perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a snippet that will show you how you can easily sort this. The major issue, however, is the following:

```
return $(a).find("#lastName").text() > $(b).find("#lastName").text();
```

The `sort()` function asks to return one of *three* values, 0 to maintain position, -1 to move it before the current element and 1 to move it after. That means that all you could ever return is *after* and not *before*, so your sort fails.

For the solution I would like to suggest using a data-attribute and no more HTML spans and styles that need to be rendered (and probably hidden afterwards), so here is my suggestion:

```
<div data-alphabetize="John Doe">John Does Content</div>
```

We can string together a couple of functions to get the correct output. We will need `prototype.slice.call` to convert the returned-by-querySelector NodeList to an Array, then we need to use `sort` to sort it alphabetically and finally we can use `forEach` to go through the array and insert the nodes in the correct position.

I am using vanilla JS - mostly to show how simple things can be done without loading up jQuery. You can, of course, do this with jQuery as well.

```js
// Turn querySelectorAll NodeList into an Array
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-alphabetize]'))
// Sort the array by data-alphabetize attribute (reverse order)
.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.getAttribute('data-alphabetize') < b.getAttribute('data-alphabetize') 
  ? 1 : -1;
})
// Insert every node in order
.forEach(function(v, i, a){
  var parent = v.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(v);
  parent.insertBefore(v, parent.childNodes[0]);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-alphabetize="Beta">Joseph Alfred <strong>Beta</strong></div>
  <div data-alphabetize="Alpha">Mark Unicode <strong>Alpha</strong></div>
  <div data-alphabetize="Gamma">Graham <strong>Gamma</strong>-Python</div>
  <div data-alphabetize="Omega">Matthew <strong>Omega</strong></div>
</div>
```